# ggplot2 : printing multiple plots in one page with a loop

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, gridextra

I have several subjects for which I need to generate a plot, as I have many subjects I'd like to have several plots in one page rather than one figure for subject. 
Here it is what I have done so far:

Read txt file with subjects name

```
subjs <- scan ("ListSubjs.txt", what = "")
```

Create a list to hold plot objects

```
pltList <- list()

for(s in 1:length(subjs))
{ 

  setwd(file.path("C:/Users/", subjs[[s]])) #load subj directory
  ifile=paste("Co","data.txt",sep="",collapse=NULL) #Read subj file
  dat = read.table(ifile)
  dat <- unlist(dat, use.names = FALSE) #make dat usable for ggplot2
  df <- data.frame(dat)

  pltList[[s]]<- print(ggplot( df, aes(x=dat)) +  #save each plot with unique name  
    geom_histogram(binwidth=.01, colour="cyan", fill="cyan") +
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept=0),   # Ignore NA values for mean
               color="red", linetype="dashed", size=1)+
   xlab(paste("Co_data", subjs[[s]] , sep=" ",collapse=NULL)))

}
```

At this point I can display the single plots for example by

```
print (pltList[1]) #will print first plot
print(pltList[2]) # will print second plot
```

I d like to have a solution by which several plots are displayed in the same page, I 've tried something along the lines of previous posts but I don't manage to make it work

for example:

```
for (p in seq(length(pltList))) {
  do.call("grid.arrange", pltList[[p]])  
}
```

gives me the following error

`Error in arrangeGrob(..., as.table = as.table, clip = clip, main = main,  : 
  input must be grobs!`

I can use more basic graphing features, but I d like to achieve this by using ggplot. Many thanks for consideration
Matilde

Answer (score 5):

Your error comes from indexing a list with `[[`:

consider

```
pl = list(qplot(1,1), qplot(2,2))
```

`pl[[1]]` returns the first plot, but `do.call` expects a *list* of arguments. You could do it with, `do.call(grid.arrange, pl[1])` (no error), but that's probably not what you want (it arranges *one plot* on the page, there's little point in doing that). Presumably you wanted all plots,

```
grid.arrange(grobs = pl)
```

or, equivalently,

```
do.call(grid.arrange, pl)
```

If you want a selection of this list, use `[`,

```
grid.arrange(grobs = pl[1:2])
do.call(grid.arrange, pl[1:2])
```

Further parameters can be passed trivially with the first syntax; with `do.call` care must be taken to make sure the list is in the correct form,

```
grid.arrange(grobs = pl[1:2], ncol=3, top=textGrob("title"))
do.call(grid.arrange, c(pl[1:2], list(ncol=3, top=textGrob("title"))))
```

Comment: Please, add the necessary imports for this (I couldn't guess the `import(gridExtra)` before I read the next answer

Answer (score 1):

```
library(gridExtra) # for grid.arrange
library(grid) 
grid.arrange(pltList[[1]], pltList[[2]], pltList[[3]], pltList[[4]], ncol = 2, main = "Whatever") # say you have 4 plots
```

OR,

```
do.call(grid.arrange,pltList)
```

Comment: Thanks for help but this does not seem to work Error in arrangeGrob(..., as.table = as.table, clip = clip, main = main,  : 
  input must be grobs!

Comment: I guess that has to do with your layout. Have a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21343372/arrangegrob-error-when-using-ggplot2-in-a-function

Answer (score 0):

I wish I had enough reputation to comment instead of answer, but anyway you can use the following solution to get it work.

I would do exactly what you did to get the pltList, then use the multiplot function from [this recipe](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_%28ggplot2%29/).  Note that you will need to specify the number of columns.  For example, if you want to plot all plots in the list into two columns, you can do this:

```
print(multiplot(plotlist=pltList, cols=2))
```

Comment: What is the multiplot fuction here ? I can't seem to find it

Comment: It's defined [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_%28ggplot2%29/)